# Why does this command crash IDA Android native debugger?

Tags: ida, android, arm

In Android shared library that heavily protected against debugging, I found following code:

```
CODE32
ldr pc, [pc, #-4]
```

For me, this instruction looks like `NOP`; it just jumps to next instruction in ARM mode. The debugged process crashes on this command, however. I use `IDA` to debug the process.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: "crashes" how, exactly?

Comment: Raises `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: IDA itself or the process being debugged?

Comment: The debugged process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This instruction is **not** a NOP. It reads memory and jumps to the address loaded. If the memory is inaccessible or the loaded address is invalid/non-executable, you will get an exception, so the debugger's behavior is correct.

a NOP-like instruction involving PC in ARM mode would be something like

```
ADD PC, PC, #-4
```

(likely disassembled as `sub pc, pc, #4` or maybe even `ADR PC, next_addr` )